# Prevent Vue bootstrap-dropdown from closing after click

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

How can I change the behaviour of a b-dropdown-item-button within a b-dropdown-component so that it does not close automatically when I click on it?

The dropdown is syntactically structured as follows:

```
<b-dropdown>
    <b-dropdown-item-button>
        <span>Mark as read</span>
    <b-dropdown-item-button>

    <b-dropdown-group>
// Messages are output here
    </b-dropdown-group>
</bdropdown>
```

Now I wonder how I can prevent the dropdown from closing when I click on the b-dropdown-item-button.

Answer (score 12):

Placing `@click.native.capture.stop` directive on any subcomponent of `<b-dropdown>` will prevent it from closing the dropdown.

For example:

```
<b-dropdown>
  <b-dropdown-item-button @click.native.capture.stop>
    <span>Mark as read</span>
  <b-dropdown-item-button>

  <b-dropdown-group @click.native.capture.stop>
    // no click will exit the parent, therefore they won't close the dropdown
  </b-dropdown-group>
</bdropdown>
```

Answer (score 1):

> - First: make a reference which you want to stay show (i.e, b-drowpdown)
> - then make an function onClick which will work on click of button
> - finally remain shown the dropdown by this.$refs.dropdown.show(true) which override the defaults

```
<template>
    <b-dropdown ref="dropdown">
        <b-dropdown-item-button @click="onClick">
            <span>Mark as read</span>
        <b-dropdown-item-button>

        <b-dropdown-group>
    // Messages are output here
        </b-dropdown-group>
    </b-dropdown>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      onClick() {
        this.$refs.dropdown.show(true)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't reopen the dropdown instead of preventing it from closing. If any functionality is bound on dropdown open event it will also run when you click inside it. It's not scale-able.

Comment: Similarly, sometimes it's needed to keep functionality same but changing of UI. It's only needed to hide or show, not relating to stop it's attitude.

Answer (score 0):

Add a prevent modifier `@click.prevent` to the element which shouldn't close the dropdown on click:

```html
<b-dropdown>
  <b-dropdown-text>
     <b-form-input @click.prevent></b-form-input>
  </b-dropdown-text>
</b-dropdown>
```

Docs:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers